# Which fields are absolutely required for PayPal credit card payments

Tags: paypal

I am currently using PayPal to handle credit card payments on my website.

I would like to know what fields are absolutely required to process a successful payment.

This is particular important to know when handling credit card payments in other countries, to be specific the address fields as other countries do not uses zip code,state....

Also is the Cvv field required?

My card payment form  includes the following  fields:

card Type:
Card Number:
Cvv Code:
First Name:
Last Name:
Expiry month and Year:
Street Address:
City:
State:
Country

While testing credit card payments with PayPal test accounts I only needed to supply the card type, number , first and last name and expiry month and year.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you have your PayPal account configured.  With Payments Pro, you can setup Fraud Management Filters within your PayPal account.  There, you can specify whether or not you want to decline cards where AVS or CVV2 does not match or if you just want to accept them (or flag them).

So, the answer to your question is "it depends on your settings."

Comment: I have PayPal payment Pro and using their API to make payments, however I do not see and option to set how credit cards are handled

Comment: Which version of Pro do you have?  "Website Payments Pro 3.0" or "PayPal Pro 2.0"?